# Normalize xml data to object linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hello I have this xml and I want to get a list of Plans and and list of PlanTerms.

```
   Plan
    {
    name = "Premium"
    List<Terms>{
      24 months/24000 miles
     36 months/36000 miles
    }

    }
```

XML:

```
<plan>
    <planid>1</planid>
    <plantitle>Premium</plantitle>
    <plandesc>12 months / 12,000 miles</plandesc>
    <planwarranty>NA</planwarranty>
    <plancoveredterm>12</plancoveredterm>

</plan>
<plan>
    <planid>2</planid>
    <plantitle>Premium</plantitle>
    <plandesc>24 months / 24,000 miles</plandesc>
    <planwarranty>NA</planwarranty>
    <plancoveredterm>24</plancoveredterm>

</plan>
<plan>
    <planid>3</planid>
    <plantitle>Premium</plantitle>
    <plandesc>36 months / 36,000 miles</plandesc>
    <planwarranty>NA</planwarranty>
    <plancoveredterm>36</plancoveredterm>

</plan>
```

I am using following code block

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(providerResponse);
XElement root = xdoc.Root;

var quotePlan = (from planInfo in root.Descendants("plan")
                 select new QuotePlanMbp
                 {
                     Name = planInfo.Element("plantitle").Value.ToString(),
                     QuoteTerms = (from planTerm in root.Descendants("plan")
                                   select new QuoteTermMbp
                                   {
                                       TermMonths = planTerm.Element("plancoveredterm").Value != null ? Convert.ToInt32(planTerm.Element("plancoveredterm").Value) : 0,
                                       TermMiles = planTerm.Element("plancoveredmiles").Value != null ? Convert.ToInt32(planTerm.Element("plancoveredmiles").Value) : 0,
                                       TermCost = planTerm.Element("plancost").Value != null ? Convert.ToDecimal(planTerm.Element("plancost").Value) : 0
                                   }).ToList<QuoteTerm>()
                  }).GroupBy(plan => plan.Name);
```

This gives me three top level plan records but I want only one Plan record (since the name is always "premium") with three terms.
Could you please suggest some tweaking to resolve this issue.

Comment: This is not valid XML because it doesnt have a single root object.

Comment: sorry missed the root element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should group your plans by name before selecting terms. Then for each plan group select list of terms:

```
from planInfo in root.Descendants("plan")
group planInfo by (string)planInfo.Element("plantitle") into g
select new QuotePlanMbp {
   Name = g.Key,
   QuoteTerms = 
      (from planTerm in g
       let months = (int?)planTerm.Element("plancoveredterm")
       select new QuoteTermMbp {
           TermMonths = months.GetValueOrDefault(),
           TermMiles = (int)((int?)planTerm.Element("plancoveredmiles") ?? 0),
           TermCost = ((int?)planTerm.Element("plancost")).GetValueOrDefault()
       }).ToList<QuoteTermMbp>()
};
```

I also showed here three different techniques for parsing integer properties of term - choose one you like more.

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much all the additional tips.